# How to globally change the default date format in Python

Tags: python, date, formatting, settings

I'm coding a Python script, in which I currently use `strftime` when I want to display a date according to a specific format. However, the format I use is consistently always the same throughout the script, thus it feels a waste of time and a violation of the DRY principle having to explicitly call `strftime(myFormat)` in every `print`.

I'm looking for a way to define only once what the date string format used in the script is, for *all* strings.

I tried this:

```
from datetime import datetime

def format_string(self):
    return "%02d-%02d-%02d" % (self._day, self._month, self._year)
datetime.date.__str__ = format_string
```

which doesn't work because `__str__` is read-only.

Comment: explicit is better then implicit (Python mantra). But you may want to lock about `locale`, and modify there out to display dates.

Comment: My comment is not exactly related to the question, but I find funny how "Explicit is better than implicit" is in the Python Zen when all type information is implicit.

Comment: Yeah, but it is recommended not to change type once you assigned a variable to a type. On the other hand there is also a Zen rule which blanked all other rules. In any case, IIRC you can also use the new `{}` format strings. There you can define/overwrite formats. Maybe using a new format letter. I do not remember exactly. I found ugly and useless, but now reading your question... there is a real use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say `__str__` was not readonly, how would your solution work when importing datetime in all modules? You would have to define the `__str__` in the beginning of each module.

To resolve that, you will probably create a base module, say "mydatetime.py", define `__str__` in that module, and then do `from mydatetime import datetime` in all modules where you"ll print

So if we are going to have our own base module, why not just create our own class

*mydatetime.py*

```
from datetime import datetime as system_datetime, date as system_date


class date(system_date):
     def __str__(self):. # similarly for __repr__
           return "%02d-%02d-%02d" % (self._day, self._month, self._year)

class datetime(system_datetime):
     def __str__(self):. # similarly for __repr__
           return "%02d-%02d-%02d" % (self._day, self._month, self._year)

     def date(self):
           return date(self.year, self.month, self.day)
```

and then you can replace all `from datetime import datetime` with `from mydatetime import datetime`

Comment: Yes thank you, it was what I tried to do. However, this approach works only with datetime instances, not with date instances. For example, `str(datetime.today())` is correctly formatted, but `str(datetime(2020, 7, 22).date()))` is not. We can subclass `date` as well as `datetime`, but we cannot (in a simple fashion) make it use the new child class we defined.

Comment: To be more precise, I meant that we can subclass `date` as well as `datetime`, but we cannot (in a simple fashion) make the original `datetime` use the new `date` child class we defined.

Comment: We can, by overriding the `date()` method in our new class

Answer (score 0):

You could define a method `pretty_format_date()` that you import across your codebase, and that method would contain the `strftime(myFormat)` to be reused.

Comment: It would be equally inconvenient to have to write everywhere `pretty_format_date(date)` as `date.strftime(myFormat)` (although I would then repeat only a method call instead of a method call + an argument). Conceptually, I'm looking for a kind of application-scale parametrization of the `datetime` / `date` behaviour (if this is even possible).

Comment: Just a way of making it DRY, so if you want to change the format string later you can easily.

Comment: The other answer (with a new class being defined) is probably closer to your needs