# Formatting todays date in python as date type

Tags: python

I'm trying to get todays date in the format %d/%m/%y without converting to a string. I still want to have the date as the data type.

Following code returns an str

```
today = date.today().strftime('%d/%m/%y')

        print(type(today))
```

Comment: not call to strftime
cause in convert it to string..

Comment: I've tried strptime but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right way to achieve your goal:

```py
from datetime import date

today = date.today()
today_string = today.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

print(type(today))
print(today_string)
```

Output:

```py
<class 'datetime.date'>
26/10/2022
```

To change the `date` class default format:

*mydatetime.py*

```py
from datetime import datetime as system_datetime, date as system_date


class date(system_date):
     def __str__(self):. # similarly for __repr__
           return "%02d-%02d-%02d" % (self._day, self._month, self._year)

class datetime(system_datetime):
     def __str__(self):. # similarly for __repr__
           return "%02d-%02d-%02d" % (self._day, self._month, self._year)

     def date(self):
           return date(self.year, self.month, self.day)
```

Read More: [How to globally change the default date format in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63035769/11100417)

Comment: This returns date in 2022-10-26. I want 10/26/2022. I dont know why it returns the wrong format. So is there a way to convert today_string as date and keep the correct format?

Comment: @tordaniel today is an object from python date class. it has its default format. if you want to change the default format you should inherit from this class and customize it

Comment: @tordaniel, This is not a wrong format 2022-10-26, this is ISO-8601. Type and format are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

The default datetime simply outputs as is; but you can inherit and create a custom `__repr__`:

```py
from datetime import datetime

class mydatetime(datetime):
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.strftime('%d/%m/%y')

mydatetime.today()
```

outputs `26/10/22`